# Delete files when match

Tags: python-3.x

I have a lot of mp3 files in directory, and I want to delete all of them that are larger than 101.

The following files are in the directory:

```
095-test.mp3
096-test.mp3
097-test.mp3
098-test.mp3
099-test.mp3
100-test.mp3
101-test.mp3
102-test.mp3
103-test.mp3
```

I would like to delete the following

```
101-test.mp3
102-test.mp3
103-test.mp3
```

code:

```
def check_files():
    count = 101
    directory = r'C:\Users\test\Music\mp31\\'
    while count <= 200:

        get = glob.glob(directory + str(count) + '*')
        if get:
            os.remove(get)

        count += 1


check_files()
```

what's wrong there?

Regards

Comment: What's the problem with your code? What error does it throw?

Comment: error: TypeError: remove: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

Comment: try changing `get = glob.glob(directory + str(count) + '*')` into `get = glob.glob(str(directory + str(count) + '*'))`

Comment: after change get same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) `glob.glob` returns a list of possible files that match the pattern, also if there is just one. To fix this you can just get the first element of that list:

```
def check_files():
    count = 101
    directory = r'C:\Users\test\Music\mp31\\'
    while count <= 200:

        get = glob.glob(directory + str(count) + '*')
        if get:
            os.remove(get[0])

        count += 1


check_files()
```

However to join paths I'd suggest you to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), that I am pretty sure should work also with windows paths.

So here's your code, with just a few changes that I think will make it work safer

```
import os
import glob
def check_files():
    directory = r'C:\Users\test\Music\mp31\\'
    for count in range(101, 201):
        get = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, str(count), '*'))
        map(os.remove, get)
check_files()
```

Comment: there is no error, but nothing is deleted either

Comment: @kulle.alle in my example I have not included the `check_files()`, just the code of the function itself, try adding `check_files()`

Comment: yes, that was clear to me, I added that myself when testing. it still doesn't work, unfortunately no error output either

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618406/access-the-class-from-a-staticmethod-defined-in-the-metaclass ? You ask, get answer, then delete, that isn't nice

Comment: @azro I realised the question had some concept-fundamental problems (I wasn't sure about the difference between a baseclass and a metaclass)